# Are these good examples of ihrer = her/their in genitive?

Tags: adjective, possessive

I am trying to understand the meaning of *ihrer* here:

> "Sie lernt mit den Kindern ihrer Freunde."

Is it correct to translate this as:

> "She is studying with her friends' children."

But if you change the verb to *lernen*:

> "Sie lernen mit den Kindern ihrer Freunde."

Does this become:

> "They are studying with their friends' children."?

I think *ihrer* can mean both *her* and *them*, but I am not sure so was trying to highlight this in the two sample phrases.

Comment: This is a type of *co-reference* resolution, same as *Ihr Zug ist da* or *Ich sehe sie*.  It is not unique to the genitive case forms.  The interpretation is a question of context.

Answer (score 3):

You are correct, *ihrer* is the personal pronoun of:

1. 3. Person Femininum Singular Genitiv (your first example)
2. 3. Person Plural Genitiv (second example)

Also note, that in your example sentences *ihrer* does not necessarily have to refer to *Sie*, though usually it would. Depending on context it could also refer to another person(s) which is/are not mentioned in this sentence.

Comment: The same problem of ambiguous reference with pronouns is frequent in English. Usually, it is easy to resolve the ambiguity based on what makes sense in the context.